# Use MySQL instead of LocalDb

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to use the default authentication system for a Web API 2 and I noticed it creates the following database :

[image]

but I have already an Entity database with MySQL. Is it possible to merge them?

Then I could add the context to the startup options like that

```
UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(MYCONTEXT));
```

Would it work?

Because I don't know how to use 2 databases with Entity. The authentication doesn't work since I replaced the EntityFramework section in the Web Config for this one

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

So is it possible to use a database first approach with the AspNet tables.

Thank you

**EDIT**

Would it be more easy to use SQL server because it's still possible to use it for this project?

Answer (score 1):

I just  want to refer you to this link as solution:

[Entity Framework Model from two databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790580/entity-framework-model-from-two-databases)

But I still think a redesign of schema using one database will be better.

Comment: Thank you, I also think 1 database would be better